# Onedrive & Googledrive automatic syncing - How often does syncing happen?

Tags: samsung, sync, google-drive, android-11, onedrive

I have the samsung a32 5g.

Does just logging into onedrive/google drive reduce performance/battery life in any way?

How often does onedrive and Googledrive sync to your phone automatically if logged in, does it affect performance/cause slowdowns constantly?